# How to get numeric data from a member function pointer for a hash?

Tags: c++, hash, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, reinterpret-cast

I want to xor my instance pointer `(size_t)` with some sort of value from a member function pointer from it, but the compiler doesn't like

```
reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(MemberFunctionPointer)
```

which otherwise works fine on a regular function pointer.  Is there any way I can pull some sort of unique value from a member function pointer to xor with the object it's from for a hash?

I suppose this is me being ignorant about the underlying difference between a standard function pointer and a member function pointer...  I will do some more research on that.  However, I would still like some way to get some sort of "size_t" value from a member function pointer - or any kind of value I can turn into a `size_t` and use to create a unique hash value.

Comment: I suppose you need to give it as [object_instance].MemberFunctionPointer (square brackets not in your code) although the whole concept seems dubious to me.

Comment: That is not guaranteed by the standard to work with regular non-member function pointers either (but it does work on many common implementations). If the member function is not `static`, then I'm fairly certain that you can't achieve what you want without diving deep into how your compiler implements member functions.

Comment: @o_weisman I don't understand... these function pointers don't point to a memory address that is set in stone like a regular pointers?  Can't I get the address they're pointing at to see if two of them are pointing at the same thing?

Comment: You can achieve what you want with some template magic; you'll need an instance of the class though to achieve this .. however, could you instead test for type equality of the objects? If the objects are the same (i.e. `if (typeid(x) == typeid(some_class)) { .. }`) then the member functions are the same for the types .. ?

Comment: @Simple Ugh... should have tried to cast to const... I couldn't cast member pointer to void*, and being inexperienced in C++ I didn't even think that const void* would make a difference.